# Ajax retornando HTML junto ao Json

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

Olá,

Estou tentando preencher dados de inputs com o resultado de uma pesquisa no banco de dados usando como filtro o que já foi digitado antes.
ex: Usuario digita codigo de cliente e ao tirar o foco do input, já é preenchido todos os campos seguintes (nome, telefone, endereco)

fiz a função abaixo usando JQuery para retornar o resultado da pesquisa feita no PHP.

```
      $(document).ready( function() {
       /* Executa a requisição quando o campo CEP perder o foco */
       $('#txtCod').blur(function(){
               /* Configura a requisição AJAX */
               $.ajax({
                    url : 'busca_cliente.php', /* URL que será chamada */ 
                    type : 'POST',  
                    data: 'cod=' + $('#txtCod').val(), /* dado que será enviado via POST */
                    dataType: 'json', /* Tipo de transmissão */
                    complete: function(resposta){
                        //o problema começa aqui !!!
                        $('#txtNome').val(resposta.nome);
                        //console.log(resposta);
                    }
               });   
       return false;    
       })
    });
```

Meu problema é que alem de retornar o JSON do que eu preciso, o codigo está retornando um trecho HTML sabe deus de onde, segue o que é retornado

```
 "<form style=display: inline; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; name=imprimecupom method=post target="_blank">
     <input type=hidden name=op>
     <input type=hidden name="pessoa">
     <input type=hidden name="tipo">
     <input type=hidden name="valorbruto">
     <input type=hidden name="horario">

  </form>


   {"cod_medico":"42","nome":"Guilherme","matricula":"122344","guia":"1","chave":"","senha":"","email":"","sexo":"","cidade":"","estado":"","contato":null,"cpf":"","espec":"","telefone":"","cep":"","endereco":"","cod_operadora":null}"
```

como fazer para ele retornar somente o JSON, e se não tiver jeito, como ignorar o HTML e só usar o JSON da resposta dada pelo Ajax, porque, com esse HTML a mais, não consigo acessar o JSON para preencher os inputs.

Obrigado a todos;

**EDIT**

Segue código de busca de cliente, por mais simples de possa ser

```
$cod = $_POST['cod'];
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE cod_cliente = '{$cod}'";
$res   = mysql_query($sql, $db); 
$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
echo json_encode($linha);
```

Comment: Coloque tambem o seu código da pagina `busca_cliente.php`

Comment: inclui aqui @RafaelAcioly

Comment: Esse é todo o conteúdo da pagina `busca_cliente.php` ?

Comment: Então, tirando a abertura e fechamento de tag php (me falaram que o fechamento pode atrapalhar também, preciso testar) eu faço um include em uma estrutura php de segurança (onde eu também crio a conexão com o banco)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Erro estava no arquivo de configuração do banco onde tinha um echo perdido que retornava o HTML.